# How to hide rows in VBA based on values in row, quickly

Tags: excel, vba, show-hide

this is my first time using the site, so forgive me for any inept explaining.  I have a working macro to hide/unhide rows based on content of the rows, I just want it to be faster.  Using a check box, when the box is checked, all rows with an "x" in column D get unhidden, those without an "x" get hidden.  Same thing happens when it is unchecked, except it references column C, not D.

Right now, this code works.  It's just a little slower than I'd like, since I'm sharing this with a bunch of people.  Any ideas for how to speed it up?  I'm pretty darn new to VB (the internet is astoundingly wise and a good teacher), but that doesn't matter.  I already improved the code - before it selected each row, then referenced the column, and it was awful.  Any ideas to speed it up (preferably without moving the screen) would be great.

Thanks so much folks,
DS

```
Sub NewLuxCheck()
    Dim x As Integer
    NumRows = Range("A42", "A398").Rows.Count
    Range("A42").Select
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes("checkbox2").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
        For x = 42 To NumRows + 41 Step 1
            If Worksheets("Base").Range("D" & x).Value = "x" Then
                Worksheets("Base").Range(x & ":" & x).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Else
                Worksheets("Base").Range(x & ":" & x).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next
    Else
        For x = 42 To NumRows + 41 Step 1
            If Worksheets("Base").Range("C" & x).Value = "x" Then
            Worksheets("Base").Range(x & ":" & x).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Else
                Worksheets("Base").Range(x & ":" & x).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next
    End If
    MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

Comment: Add as a first line to your sub: `Application.ScreenUpdating = false` and add the other line right before `Msgbox ("Done")`: `Application.ScreenUpdating = true`

Comment: That works perfectly.  Wow, it's instantaneous now.  Good to know.  Thanks, that's great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use array formula and let Excel to return array with row-numbers where 'x' value occures. *It will be quicker but you'll have to reorganise your code and create separate functions etc.*

Here example where array formula finds rows whre in column 'D' the cell has value 'x'. Then string of this row numbers is created in form of "A1,A5,A10" ...means 'x' was found in rows 1,5,10. And finally Range(rowsJoind).EntireRow.Hidden is used for all the rows to be hidden/un-hidden in one step.

For rows with value different then 'x' you'll have to use formula like '=IF({0}<>""x"", ROW({0}), -1)'.

```
Sub test()
    Dim inputRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim myFormula As String
    Dim rowsJoined As String, i As Long
    Dim result As Variant

    With Worksheets("Base")
        lastRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set inputRange = .Columns("D").Resize(lastRow)

        Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1
        myFormula = "=IF({0}=""x"", ROW({0}), -1)"
        myFormula = VBA.Strings.Replace(myFormula, "{0}", inputRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1))
        result = Application.Evaluate(myFormula)
        result = Application.Transpose(result)
        Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1

        For i = LBound(result) To UBound(result)
            If (result(i) > -1) Then
                rowsJoined = rowsJoined & "A" & result(i) & IIf(i < UBound(result), ",", "")
            End If
        Next i

        .Range(rowsJoined).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is a great idea.  Turns out a big source of lag was simply that the screen was updating as it went, so I turned that off, thanks to KazJaw.  But I'll be expanding the functionality of this tool, so I'll use this idea of creating a string, then hiding the rows.  Thanks so much!!

Comment: I don't totally understand all that's going on here, but it looks good.  I think though that the string needs to be longer - is there a way to expand the maximum length of a string?

Comment: @user2658468 Which string needs to be longer? Max. length of string in VBA is according to help: 'A variable-length string can contain up to approximately 2 billion (2^31) characters.' This is not enought for you?